# Stopping android service in case of force closing

Tags: android, android-service, activity-lifecycle, ondestroy, forceclose

In my android application, it runs a Service in the background. It is a media player application. The service is started whenever the play button is pressed and the service is stopped whenever the user presses the stop button or normally closes the application. Actually, I am calling the stopService() method before closing the foreground activity. I need to keep the service alive during screen rotations. So, I am not stopping the Service in onDestroy() method of the foreground activity. But I did notice that the service is not stopping in case of force closing, if it happens for some reason.

Now, how can I stop the service in case of force closing? Is there any particular listener which will allow to do a final job before force closing of an activity other than onDestroy()?

Comment: What do you mean by **force closing**? A back button press or something else?

Comment: Ideal apps should not force close. Try to fix the bug :) and use exception handling.

Comment: Actually it is force closing on the emulator for some ad sdk I think. It have not happend on the real device yet. I want to do that for precaution.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the code sections that can cause a force close in a standard try {} catch {} block and stop the service if any exception is caught.

Comment: I think the force closing is happening in some ad sdk I have integrated. So, I do not have access in their code.